# PowerShell: System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile won't download files collected from ListDirectory

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, webclient, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to download some zip files from an FTP server. The FTP server is structured like this

```
ftp://ftp.example.com
|
 -> /Download
    | 
     -> file1.zip, file2.zip, file3.zip etc
```

I have pulled all of the files into an array called `$ftpFiles`

```
foreach ($zip in $ftpFiles)
{
    $LocalFile = "C:\Temp\$zip"
    $RemoteFile = "$site/$zip"
    $ftp = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $realPassword)
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$RemoteFile")
    $ftp.DownloadFile($uri, $LocalFile)
    Write-Host "$zip download complete"
}
```

The problem is `$ftp.DownloadFile` will not work with my `$LocalFile` variable. However, if I manually input the `$LocalFile` information it will.

For example

```
$ftp.DownloadFile($uri, "C:\temp\file1.zip")
```

works just fine, but

```
$ftp.DownloadFile($uri, $LocalFile)
```

gives me the following error

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:34
 +                 $ftp.DownloadFile <<<< ($uri, $LocalFile)
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

For debugging purposes I have been doing

```
write-host $LocalFile
```

which will return correctly as

```
C:\Temp\file1.zip
```

As I expected.

I can only assume that `DownloadFile` doesn't like the nested variable and is reading it as `C:\Temp\$zip` and I'm not sure how I can go about fixing it.

EDIT: Comments want to see how the `$files` array is built

```
$site = $ftpbase + $dir

$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$site")
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory #Details
$ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $realPassword)

$response = $ftp.getresponse() 
$stream = $response.getresponsestream() 

$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024 
$encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding 

$outputBuffer = "" 
$foundMore = $false 

## Read all the data available from the stream, writing it to the 
## output buffer when done. 
do 
{

    ## Allow data to buffer for a bit 
    start-sleep -Seconds 2 

    ## Read what data is available 
    $foundmore = $false 
    $stream.ReadTimeout = 1000

    do 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            $read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024) 

            if($read -gt 0) 
            { 
                $foundmore = $true 
                $outputBuffer += ($encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $read))

            } 
        } catch { $foundMore = $false; $read = 0 } 
    } while($read -gt 0) 
} 
while($foundmore)

$files = $outputBuffer -split ("\n")
```

Comment: Use [Join-Path](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) to build your path as per powershell best practice.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not fix my issue.

Comment: *"I can only assume that DownloadFile doesn't like the nested variable and is reading it as C:\Temp\$zip"* - That just a nonsense. The `DownloadFile` does not even get to know that a variable was used. You code works. I've tested it.

Comment: Catch the exception and see if there's any inner exception.

Comment: Does C:\Temp\file1.zip already exist?

Comment: Is `$ftpFiles` just a plain string array? Show us how you've initialized it

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It sounds like nonsense to me as well, but I can't figure it out otherwise. I did a try catch on the whole thing and there was no other execption.

Comment: @Matt No it does not.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No, it's an array

    $ftpFiles.GetType()
    System.Array

Comment: There's must be an inner exception. That's what the top-level exception says, after all.

Comment: As @MathiasR.Jessen wrote, show us how you create the array.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Added to the OP at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the `ListDirectory` is in ASCII mode, where lines are separated by `\r\n`. You split the output by the `\n` only, so the `\r` is kept in the file name.

Consequently the download fails, as the file `file1.zip\r` does not exist.

When you print `file1.zip\r`, you won't see the `\r`.